# Error in my timed motion Zelle graphics.py program

Tags: python, time, zelle-graphics

I tried to make a program into which you enter a speed (pixels per second), so a point in the window will move at that exact speed on the x axis.
I enter the speed, but the point isn't moving and IDLE does not complain with an error.

```
from graphics import *
import time
win=GraphWin("Time", 600, 600)
point=Point(50, 100)
point.setFill("green")
point.draw(win)
speed=Entry(Point(100,50), 15)
speed.setText("Pixels per second")
speed.draw(win)
win.getMouse()
speed1=speed.getText()

speed1=eval(speed1)
t=0.0
time=time.clock()

if time==t+1:
   t+=1
   point.move(speed1, 0)
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?  I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: it doesn't move. Maybe its because this is not the right time method?, I don't have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't move because this is not a loop:

```
if time==t+1:
   t+=1
   point.move(speed1, 0)
```

`time` isn't `==`, nor `>=`, to `t+1` so it goes past and the program is finished.  What you need is:

```
import time
from graphics import *

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600, 600

win = GraphWin("Time", WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)

circle = Circle(Point(50, 200), 10)
circle.setFill("green")
circle.draw(win)

speed = Entry(Point(100, 50), 15)
speed.setText("Pixels per second")
speed.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
velocity = float(speed.getText())

t = time.clock()

while circle.getCenter().x < WINDOW_WIDTH:
    if time.clock() >= t + 1:
        t += 1
        circle.move(velocity, 0)
```

I used a larger object as it was just too hard to see the 1 pixel bright green point moving.

Answer (score 0):

The number of seconds returned by `time.clock()` is a floating-point number.  The likelihood that it will happen to be equal to `t+1` is low enough that your point very rarely moves.  Instead of using `==`, use `>=`:

```
if time >= t + 1:
    t += 1
    point.move(speed1, 0)
```

Comment: i tried it, it gave me this error: TypeError: unorderable types: module() >= float()

Comment: You should be changing just the `if` line.  If you are getting that error, it looks like you removed the `time = time.clock()` line.

Comment: speed1=eval(speed1)
t=0.0
start=time.clock()

if time>=t+1:
    t+=1
    point.move(speed1, 0)

Comment: the time =time.clock() is the sam

Comment: Two comments up you gave the clue: `start=time.clock()`, not `time=time.clock()`.  Change the `if` to `if start>= t + 1:`

Comment: Changed it, still not works! But this time it doesn't give me an error

Comment: Does it move at all?